# How can I get a sword with sharpness 1000?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'd like to create a sharpness 1000 sword - I've seen my friends do it but they won't tell me how they were able to get this to work.

I have also tried many methods on YouTube but they all don't work for me.

I am playing on Xbox One.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible on the Bedrock edition without mods.